# How to get the error message in Perl when a backtick command fails

Tags: perl, svn

I have a variable `$deployment_tarfile` which contains a tar file with its svn location. In my Perl script backtick command I use

```
$depsvn = `svn ls $deployment_tarfile`
```

to check whether the file is present in the svn or not. If it fails then how can we log the error message?

Currently, if the command fails then it just displays in the shell. I want to print it specifically. How can I do that?

I have tried `$!` but it doesn't display.

```
$depsvn = `svn ls $deployment_tarfile`;
if ( $? != 0 ) {
    print "$!"; # It displays blank
}
```

I have also tried `$OS_ERROR` and `$ERRNO` instead of `$!` but it didn't work.

How can I print the error message in Perl if the svn command fails?

Updates: I am using Perl version 5.8.8

Comment: Do you need the output of the Subversion command? If not then you should be using `my $stat = system('svn', 'ls', $deployment_tarfile)` and checking the exit status. If you *do* need the output as well as the exit status then you should look at [IPC::Open2](http://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Open2)
or even [IPC::Open3](http://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Open3)
if you need to see STDERR as well

Comment: Why are you calling the command-line client instead of using [`SVN::Client`](http://search.cpan.org/~mlanier/Alien-SVN-1.6.12.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm)?

Comment: Yes I need the output of the Subversion command. I will try IPC::Open2 IPC::Open3.Thanks for information.

Comment: I am new to perl script and didn't know about SVN::Client and IPC::Open2.I will try to use these.

Comment: @alroc, Thanks for introducing me to SVN::Client but it is not supported in python 5.8.8.

Comment: You don't need python support if your script is in Perl as you describe in your post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. I meant perl 5.8.8. Sorry for mentioning it wrong

Answer (score 5):

`$!` and friends report OS level errors.  "File not found", "Out of Space" and the like.  `svn` on the other hand is reporting it's application level errors to `STDERR`.

As such you can either redirect `svn`'s `STDERR` to it's `STDOUT` (easy enough to do as you are invoking the shell by adding `2>&1` to the end of the shell command) or to use something like `IPC::Run3` or `IPC::Run`, to get `STDOUT` & `STDERR` independently.

... of course alroc's recommendation of an SVN specific module is probably more applicable to this *specific* case.

Comment: I did try  $depsvn = `svn ls $deployment_tarfile 2>$1`; and it worked also. but is there any special variable in perl script which can give error directly?

Comment: @Nitu, You want to catch what's `svn` *prints to a handle*. If you want that in a variable, you need to provide `svn` with a pipe handle, and read what it prints to the pipe from the other end of the pipe, and store that in a variable. That's what IPC::Run3's `run3` does for you.

Comment: Thanks ikegami for the explaination.

Answer (score 5):

For more sophisticated program execution, use [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use IPC::Run3;

my $file = shift;

my($out, $err);
run3( ['svn', 'ls', $file], undef, \$out, \$err );
if( $? ) {
    say "svn ls failed: $err";
}
else {
    say "svn ls succeeded: $out";
}
```

If you want STDOUT and STDERR in the same place, you can supply the same variable in both spots.

```
my $out;
run3( ['svn', 'ls', $file], undef, \$out, \$out );
if( $? ) {
    say "svn ls failed: $out";
}
else {
    say "svn ls succeeded: $out";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. But currently I am using python version 5.8.8 which does not support IPC::Run3 and IPC::Run.

Comment: @Nitu I trust you meant Perl. [IPC::Run and IPC::Run3 should work with 5.8.8](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=IPC-Run3+0.048). However, 5.8.8 is nine years old and I strongly suggest you upgrade. Using [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) will make that process easier.

Comment: Yes Schwern,I meant Perl only. Thanks for pointing it. and I tried using IPC::Run but it said not supported.

Comment: @Nitu What do you mean "not supported"? Did you get a message like `Can't locate IPC/Run3.pm in @INC`? This means it's just not installed.